# How to extract OLE file from Word(.Docx) by OpenXML through C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I want to use `Openxml` to abstract `"OLE package"` from an `".docx"` file. I don't know how to do it, and I didn't find any example about it in official examples. Please help me.

This is my attempt:

1. I build a Docx file by "MS office 2016" named `"Test.docx"`, and insert an `".zip"` file into `"Test.docx"`. I open `"Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool"` to Watch `"Test.docx"`, I find this([Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs9aB.jpg)), but I don't get any information about how to extract this zip file through the reflect code.
2. Then I try to use C# and `SharpCompress.dll` to extract this `".zip"` file, next is the code:

   ```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filepath = @"C:\Users\宇宙无敌帅小伙\Desktop\test.docx";

            OleFileTest(filepath);
        }

        public static void OleFileTest(string filepath)
        {
            try
            {
                using (WordprocessingDocument Docx = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filepath, true))
                {
                    Body body = Docx.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

                    IEnumerable<EmbeddedObjectPart> embd1 = Docx.MainDocumentPart.EmbeddedObjectParts;

                    int cnt = 0;
                    foreach (EmbeddedObjectPart item in embd1)
                    {
                        System.IO.Stream dt = item.GetStream(FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(dt);
                        byte[] bt = new byte[dt.Length];

                        using (FileStream fs = File.Open($"C:\\Users\\宇宙无敌帅小伙\\Desktop\\{cnt}.zip", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                        {

                            fs.Write(bt, 0, bt.Length);
                        }
                        cnt++;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
   ```

But I couldn't open this `".zip"` file which I extracted.
Can somebody help me? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The challenge is that the binary file you extract from the `EmbeddedObjectPart` is **not** your ZIP file. It is a **structured storage file** that **contains** your ZIP file.

The following unit test shows how you can extract a ZIP file (e.g., `ZipContents.zip`) that was embedded into a Word document (`"Resources\\ZipContainer.docx"`) as an OLE object, using Microsoft Word. Note the usage of the `Ole10Native.ExtractFile()` method, which extracts the ZIP file from the structured storage file (e.g., `oleObject1.bin`) embedded in your Word document.

```cs
using System.IO;
using CodeSnippets.Windows;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using Xunit;

namespace CodeSnippets.Tests.OpenXml.Wordprocessing
{
    public class EmbeddedObjectPartTests
    {
        private static void ExtractFile(EmbeddedObjectPart part, string destinationFolderPath)
        {
            // Determine the file name and destination path of the binary,
            // structured storage file.
            string binaryFileName = Path.GetFileName(part.Uri.ToString());
            string binaryFilePath = Path.Combine(destinationFolderPath, binaryFileName);

            // Ensure the destination directory exists.
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationFolderPath);

            // Copy part contents to structured storage file.
            using (Stream partStream = part.GetStream())
            using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(binaryFilePath))
            {
                partStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }

            // Extract the embedded file from the structured storage file.
            Ole10Native.ExtractFile(binaryFilePath, destinationFolderPath);

            // Remove the structured storage file.
            File.Delete(binaryFilePath);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void CanExtractEmbeddedZipFile()
        {
            const string documentPath = "Resources\\ZipContainer.docx";
            const string destinationFolderPath = "Output";
            string destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(destinationFolderPath, "ZipContents.zip");

            using WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
                WordprocessingDocument.Open(documentPath, false);

            // Extract all embedded objects.
            foreach (EmbeddedObjectPart part in wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.EmbeddedObjectParts)
            {
                ExtractFile(part, destinationFolderPath);
            }

            Assert.True(File.Exists(destinationFilePath));
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the gist of the `Ole10Native` class, which was once published by Microsoft but is a bit hard to find nowadays:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace CodeSnippets.Windows
{
    public class Ole10Native
    {
        public static void ExtractFile(string sourceFilePath, string destinationFolder)
        {
            StgOpenStorage(sourceFilePath, null, STGM.READWRITE | STGM.SHARE_EXCLUSIVE, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out IStorage iStorage);
            ProcessPackage(iStorage, destinationFolder);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(iStorage);
        }

        private static void ProcessPackage(IStorage pStg, string destinationFolder)
        {
            uint numReturned;
            pStg.EnumElements(0, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out IEnumSTATSTG pEnumStatStg);
            var ss = new STATSTG[1];

            // Loop through the STATSTG structures in the storage.
            do
            {
                // Retrieve the STATSTG structure
                pEnumStatStg.Next(1, ss, out numReturned);
                if (numReturned != 0)
                {
                    //System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.STATSTG statstm;
                    var bytT = new byte[4];

                    // Check if the pwcsName contains "Ole10Native" stream which contain the actual embedded object
                    if (ss[0].pwcsName.Contains("Ole10Native"))
                    {
                        // Get the stream objectOpen the stream
                        pStg.OpenStream(ss[0].pwcsName, IntPtr.Zero, (uint) STGM.READ | (uint) STGM.SHARE_EXCLUSIVE, 0,
                            out IStream pStream);

                        //pStream.Stat(out statstm, (int) STATFLAG.STATFLAG_DEFAULT);

                        IntPtr position = IntPtr.Zero;

                        // File name starts from 7th Byte.
                        // Position the cursor to the 7th Byte.
                        pStream.Seek(6, 0, position);

                        var ulRead = new IntPtr();
                        var filename = new char[260];
                        int i;

                        // Read the File name of the embedded object
                        for (i = 0; i < 260; i++)
                        {
                            pStream.Read(bytT, 1, ulRead);
                            pStream.Seek(0, 1, position);
                            filename[i] = (char) bytT[0];
                            if (bytT[0] == 0) break;
                        }

                        var path = new string(filename, 0, i);

                        // Next part is the source path of the embedded object.
                        // Length is unknown. Hence, loop through each byte to read the 0 terminated string
                        // Read the source path.
                        for (i = 0; i < 260; i++)
                        {
                            pStream.Read(bytT, 1, ulRead);
                            pStream.Seek(0, 1, position);
                            filename[i] = (char) bytT[0];
                            if (bytT[0] == 0) break;
                        }

                        // Unknown 4 bytes
                        pStream.Seek(4, 1, position);

                        // Next 4 byte gives the length of the temporary file path
                        // (Office uses a temporary location to copy the files before inserting to the document)
                        // The length is in little endian format. Hence conversion is needed
                        pStream.Read(bytT, 4, ulRead);
                        ulong dwSize = 0;
                        dwSize += (ulong) (bytT[3] << 24);
                        dwSize += (ulong) (bytT[2] << 16);
                        dwSize += (ulong) (bytT[1] << 8);
                        dwSize += bytT[0];

                        // Skip the temporary file path
                        pStream.Seek((long) dwSize, 1, position);

                        // Next four bytes gives the size of the actual data in little endian format.
                        // Convert the format.
                        pStream.Read(bytT, 4, ulRead);
                        dwSize = 0;
                        dwSize += (ulong) (bytT[3] << 24);
                        dwSize += (ulong) (bytT[2] << 16);
                        dwSize += (ulong) (bytT[1] << 8);
                        dwSize += bytT[0];

                        // Read the actual file content
                        var byData = new byte[dwSize];
                        pStream.Read(byData, (int) dwSize, ulRead);

                        // Create the file
                        var bWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(Path.Combine(destinationFolder, GetFileName(path)),
                            FileMode.Create));
                        bWriter.Write(byData);
                        bWriter.Close();
                    }
                }
            } while (numReturned > 0);

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pEnumStatStg);
        }

        private static string GetFileName(string filePath)
        {
            return Regex.Replace(filePath, @"^.*[\\]", "");
        }
    }
}
```

You can find the full source code (including the `Ole10Native` class) in my [CodeSnippets](https://github.com/ThomasBarnekow/CodeSnippets) GitHub repository.