# How to attach .eml file in Excel using OpenXML SDK?

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am using this code. It does attach the file but I can't see anything if I open the file using MS Excel application.

```
            string targetFile = "test returns tracker.xlsx";
            string placeholder = @"placeholder.PNG";
            string embed = @"embed.docx";
            using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(targetFile, true))
            {
                WorkbookPart workbookpart = document.WorkbookPart;
                WorksheetPart sheet1 = workbookpart.WorksheetParts.First();   


                EmbeddedPackagePart newEmbeddedPackagePart = sheet1.AddNewPart<EmbeddedPackagePart>(@"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "rId100");
                newEmbeddedPackagePart.FeedData(File.Open(embed, FileMode.Open));
                document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
                // Close the document handle.
                document.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Do you have the [Open XML Productivity Tool for Microsoft Office](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) or the [Open XML Package Editor for Modern Visual Studios](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bsivanov.OpenXMLPackageEditorforVisualStudio)? Did you look at the Open XML parts and markup created when you embed a Word document using Microsoft Excel? You would see that you'd have to do much more than add an `EmbeddedPackagePart` and feed some data (which you have done correctly).

Comment: I think what I am missing is converting this EmbeddedPackagePart  to OLEObject.

Comment: You are missing (1) multiple parts and related markup and (2) a file conversion. One, among other things, you need to add the right markup to the `WorksheetPart` (meaning you need to add an `x:oleObjects` element to the `x:worksheet` root element). Two, you are right in that you need to convert the `EmbeddedPackagePart` contents to a "structured storage file" (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59106776/how-to-extract-ole-file-from-word-docx-by-openxml-through-c-sharp/59110419#59110419)). Did you already add the right markup and all that's left is the "OLE conversion"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newEmbeddedPackagePart.FeedData(File.Open(embed...
```

Issue in your code is with FeedData. File.Open method gives you a stream but that's empty. You need to seek the data before you can expect that saved In excel as embedded doc

Example of seek is

```
    FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
    SourceStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
```

Use this source stream in your FeedData to make it work.

```
newEmbeddedPackagePart.FeedData(SourceStream);
```

Now you can save the workbook and close the document

References:

1. http://www.ericwhite.com/blog/forums/topic/adding-workbook-to-chart-as-an-embeddedpackagepart/
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @NBT Please mark the post as answered if it helps you get a solution

Comment: What I am trying to do is insert it as OLE object. Unfortunately it is not straightforward compared to Excel COM interop.

Comment: @NBT, can you confirm that this really answered your question? Firstly, when you open an **existing** file, using `FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open)`, `stream` is **not** empty, meaning `stream.Length` is greater than `0`. Secondly, you don't need to "seek the data", because `stream.Position` is equal to `0` after opening. Thirdly, `SourceStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End)` sets the position to the end of the stream, not to the beginning. Calling the `FeedData()` method after that will not feed any data.