# Change uppercases from black to red for each text boxi n all slides of power point

Tags: vba, office365, powerpoint

I need help! I´m an ESL English teacher. I´m doing my class planning in Power Point and I need to change all the Uppercases of each text box in all slides from black to red. I´m not a programmer, so I don´t know how to do this. Please, help me.

Comment: See: [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Use this in a regular module in your project:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ColourCapitalLetters()

    Dim oSlide As Slide
    Dim oShapes As Shapes
    Dim oShape As Shape
    Dim I As Long
            
    For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        Set oShapes = oSlide.Shapes
        For Each oShape In oShapes
            If oShape.HasTextFrame Then
                If oShape.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    Debug.Print oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                    For I = 1 To Len(oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text)
                        If LCase(Mid(oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, I, 1)) <> Mid(oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, I, 1) Then
                            oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(I, 1).Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                        End If
                    Next I
                End If
            End If
        Next oShape
    Next oSlide
                
End Sub
```

[image: example]
[image: VBA Module]

Comment: That turns all upper characters into red.... I believe OP wants completely upper case entire words.

Comment: Hm... It's hard to tell with the question, I still think the question indicated all uppercase characters... Easy enough though, after you find a capital, loop ahead until you find a space or punctuation.

Comment: Ah good point... easiest fix would be to `<> lower()` Will fix

Comment: cameron You may be correct on the question, rereading it again, it isn't clear. I guess I assumed for the hardest...

@Maigualida... you're an English Teacher make it easy for us with a clear question?!? =)

Comment: @pgSystemTester Good point! Please make the question easy to interpret, also please note that questions generally will not be answered if you do not make some attempt to solve yourself... I've just never written a script for PowerPoint, so found it interesting.

Comment: me too... I voted to close but was also curious about ppt objects.   [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hm... I can't think of a case where the single amended `<> LCase()` statement doesn't work.

Comment: Agreed. I didn't see it. Less is better. And I was just excited to capitalize the `5` in 5 o'clock happy hour...

Comment: Hey you seem like a nice guy, [Check out this bit I wrote I'm quite proud of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73322959/how-to-extract-a-plain-text-file-from-word/73327122#73327122) I think it's going to be relegated to the discarded bin, but it was fun to write.

Comment: Upvoted. It's the journey of producing the answer, not if it gets  (or at least that's what I tell myself when I'm bitter I didn't get any upvotes for a viable solution I produced). The post I've poured the most work/fun into [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46509572/excel-formula-based-function-for-sha256-sha512-hashing-without-vba-or-macros/56767828#56767828).

Comment: Cheers! Very impressive. No idea what I'm looking at. You're doing data encryption/decryption?